# Error: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Homepage#welcome with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, npm, webpack, rubygems

I'm trying to combine react with rails for a hello world app.
I following (https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) for tutorial and be stuck when I add

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= react_component("Indexblog", { greeting: "Hello from react-rails." }) %>
```

to my view file.

The erorr show:

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Homepage#welcome
Showing C:/Users/Hieu Vo/Desktop/simpleblog/myblogg/app/views/homepage/welcome.html.erb where line #4 raised:

Webpacker can't find application.js in C:/Users/Hieu Vo/Desktop/simpleblog/myblogg/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
```

anyone can help me ? I trying to research very much but still not resolve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1674

Comment: See if this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113179/webpackermanifestmissingentryerror-in-homeindex/58108107#58108107