# Rails: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Home#index
    Showing /Users/khalidhosein/Desktop/myEPKmedia/builder/khalid101/app/views/layouts/embedded_app.html.erb where line #7 raised:

```
Webpacker can't find hello_react.js in /Users/khalidhosein/Desktop/myEPKmedia/builder/khalid101/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
  "application.js": "/packs/application-68dcba18197451fbb79e.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/application-68dcba18197451fbb79e.js.map"
}
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

    <% application_name = ShopifyApp.configuration.application_name %>
    <title><%= application_name %></title>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Rails.root: /Users/khalidhosein/Desktop/myEPKmedia/builder/khalid101

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/embedded_app.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_embedded_app_html_erb___4509380428416253144_70127991029820'
Request
Parameters:

None
```

I am getting this error when trying to connect my Rails app with a React front end. I've tried researching and re-configuring files from all sources. I have also recreated manifiest.json files and packs libraries. I am following this tutorial:

```
https://github.com/natemacinnes/natemacinnes.github.io/blob/master/rails-5-shopify-app-setup.md
```

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated as there isn't much documentation or tutorials out there going over connecting Rails Shopify API with React.

MY CODE---->https://github.com/KhalidH82/ShopifyApp-React-Rails

Comment: `bundle exec rake webpacker:compile`

Comment: this post worked for me after so long if you are facing incompatibility with node version and webpacker use the command mentioned in this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70326851/17656942

Answer (score 37):

Though I am not using react, but was getting the same error on a newly created Rails 6 app. Reinstalling webpacker fixed it for me:

`bundle exec rake webpacker:install`

I guess it probably was some missing dependency, or a bug in an older version (I noticed `webpack-dev-server` version was upgraded to `3.8.1`).

Comment: OK since this is the top voted answer and is accurate without the whole story I will leave more clarity: there are basically 6 different reasons why this happens, nearly all of them leading to you haven't installed the Node modules using `yarn install` or `node install`. Many of the setup tools, like the installers, run those as a byproduct, which is why so many people have seen what looks like different solutions to the same root issue. I got a PR into webpacker to expand the error message (it now has 6 reasons!) based on this SO post, but now Webpacker is dead. Long live webpacker!

Comment: Using webpacker with VueJS, I had to do `bundle exec rake webpacker:install:vue`

Answer (score 22):

I had to same challenge when trying to set up a new **Rails 6** application in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

When I start the rails server, and go to my browser I get the error:

```
Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Books#index
Showing /home/promisepreston/dynamic_authorization/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Webpacker can't find application in /home/promisepreston/dynamic_authorization/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I had not setup `webpacker` in the **Rails 6** application. Starting with **Rails 6**, `webpacker` is the default JavaScript compiler. It means that all the JavaScript code will be handled by `webpacker` instead of the old assets pipeline aka `sprockets`.

To install `webpacker` in your Rails 6 application simply run the command:

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

OR

```
rails webpacker:install
```

This should successfully install `webpacker` and all of its dependencies.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: `rails webpacker:install` worked for me, tanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

may be you missed to install `npm install`. I faced exactly same issue which you have mention. Just type `npm install` in your terminal or `Dockerfile`. I hope this issue will be solved.

```
$ npm install
```

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen to you if you accidentally do not install webpacker. this can happen to you if you try to install webpacker with an incompatible version of Node

`yarn add @rails/webpacker`

notice you will get:

```
% yarn add @rails/webpacker
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error @npmcli/fs@1.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16". Got "15.14.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

you'll notice no changes will be made to your `package.json` file.

Because this check runs now (at the yarn install time) and not during runtime, it's easy to miss this.

If you fail to notice the yarn add has given you this error, you will think webpacker has been installed into your package.json when it hasn't.

Switching to a compatible node version and rerunning the installer fixes the problem. As it says, you need node version that is **^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16**

Comment: This was my exact problem, THANK YOU! I have no idea how I was supposed to know my version of Node was outdated. I'm fairly surprised at the wide variety of solutions I'm seeing to this problem actually.

Comment: @Eduardo06sp -- I thought so too so I decided to fix the error message here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/3232 . Looks like the webpacker team will accept my PR (maybe?)

Comment: Is it necessary to delete/remove the `yarn.lock` file prior to this step?

Comment: @J.R.BobDobbs -- you definitely do not want to delete the lockfile during this step-- it is determining ALL of the JS versions loading through NPMs and you don't want to just change it around. The Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError happens because Node or Yarn haven't actually or correctly installed the packages into `/node_modules` for you in development. in production/deployment, the pipeline builds your node modules, but it must build the exact same versions as what's in your `yarn.lock`, which is why you use the lockfile to dictate the versions of your node packages.

Comment: Thank you. My problem has been solved with your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with this error for a long time and none of the solutions above worked for me (try them they fix the issue 95% of the time).

For me what worked was that my version of **Node** was too recent. I had to downgrade it !

I was : **rails** Rails 6.0.4.1 and **node** 16.9.1.

I "downgraded" node to 12.13.0 which is a stable version. And now it works perfectly.

To "downgrade" node i followed this thread : [How to downgrade Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness. 

I've been on this for 2 hours, and finally a solution that works. I know this kind of comment is usually frowned upon, but thankthankthankthank you

Comment: For you Rails devs new to Node: the ODD Versions of Node are unstable; the EVEN versions of Node are the "stable ones". Node 12 and 14 happen to currently be in "maintenance" mode but for us Rails developers-- go with Node 14 for now. (Dec 2021). It'll take a while before all the interoperability stuff with Node 16 will be worked out. Just consider that the Node team is ahead of where the rest of us are adopting so it makes sense. I'd recommend the latest 14.x node.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after updating to Rails 5.1 and Webpacker 5.x

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/5-x-stable/docs/integrations.md#react

The command now is
`bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for after trying so many different solutions!

1. `yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org`
2. `rm yarn.lock`
3. `yarn`

and then install webpack again

1. `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`

[Github issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5865#issuecomment-674327500)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved the error in Rails 7 on Ubuntu 20

- I install Webpacker `bundle exec rake webpacker:install`
- Then I run `bundle exec rails assets:precompile`

`

Comment: This solution works for me. Thanks @dennis-kamau

It was failing during precompile, I found the solution for opnessl from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I already had **Webpacker** installed for my `Rails 6.0` app.

The problem was that **some of my custom js files had names containing dots** (eg. `jquery.slimscroll.js`) and they didn't seem to be compiled at all.

I don't know if this is a bug or I misconfigured something but changing the file names to new ones without dots (eg. `jquery_slimscroll.js`) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on new application reinstalling the webpacker did it for me.
`rails webpacker:install`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo bundle exec rails webpacker:install:react
```

Comment: Using VueJS: `bundle exec rake webpacker:install:vue`

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, my parallel test become failing in many feature specs. Over 30% spec failed. And in all logs I saw these strings: `Rails: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError`. Multiple restarting has no effect.

Then I'd run:

```
rm -rf public/packs-test
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
```

It fixed! All specs become to green.